# Plotly Express Bar Chart TypeError: cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am trying to plot a plotly express bar chart with dash. I copied the code from the dash gallery and filled in my values: dfs is a panda Dataframe and "Kostenartenbeschr", "Wert", "Kostenarten_vereinfacht", "Periode", "EWB" are all columns in dfs.

```
dcc.Graph(figure = px.bar(dfs, x="Kostenartenbeschr", y="Wert", 
                          color="Kostenart_vereinfacht", barmode="group",
       facet_row= "EWB", 
       facet_col= "Periode",
       category_orders= {"Periode": dfs["Periode"].drop_duplicates().astype("str"), 
                         "EWB": ["E","W","B","All"]                            }
          )
),
```

The error says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Dashboard.py", line 120, in <module>
    "EWB": ["E","W","B","All"]                            }
  File "C:\Users\TO3THY0\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\DataScience\Lib\site-packages\plotly\express\_chart_types.py", line 313, in bar
    layout_patch=dict(barmode=barmode),
  File "C:\Users\TO3THY0\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\DataScience\Lib\site-packages\plotly\express\_core.py", line 1332, in make_figure
    args, grouper, grouped
  File "C:\Users\TO3THY0\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\DataScience\Lib\site-packages\plotly\express\_core.py", line 1309, in get_orderings
    orders[col].append(val)
  File "C:\Users\TO3THY0\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\DataScience\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 1553, in append
    verify_integrity=verify_integrity)
  File "C:\Users\TO3THY0\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\DataScience\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 206, in concat
    copy=copy)
  File "C:\Users\TO3THY0\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\DataScience\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 263, in __init__
    raise TypeError("cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object")
TypeError: cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object
```

I tried `dfs["EWB"].drop_duplicates().astype(str)` instead of `["E","W","B","All"]` but that doesn't work too. What do they mean with Non NDFrame? I know my list is just one dimensional but the documentation says it hast to be a list or array_like or a column of panda df. Thanks for your help!

It was asked for a mcve:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

dfs = pd.read_csv("T_SAP_IST.txt", sep=";", encoding="latin-1", low_memory=False)

app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(figure=px.bar(dfs, x="Kostenartenbeschr", y="Wert", 
                          color="Kostenart_vereinfacht", barmode="group",
       facet_row= "EWB", 
       facet_col= "Periode",
       category_orders= {"Periode": dfs["Periode"].drop_duplicates().astype("str"), 
                         "EWB": ["E","W","B","All"]                            }
          ))
])

app.run_server(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

Comment: Do you mind to provide a [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Comment: Unforunately I can not share the dfs DataFrame. But I added a mcve to my question

Comment: If you don't share (at least) a dummy dataset it will be very hard to help you. One question why do you need dash here?